Does VS code make a local copy of ssh server directory automatically?
I normally work with vscode on a ssh server, but this server is currently down, and it will be for a month or so. I didn't manually make any backup or copy. Does vscode make any local backups on my laptop that I can I access to?
I tried going into '/home//.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage' and check there the latest modified files, but I don't know if that is what I am looking for.
